# Conditional string replacement

Tags: python, regex, regexp-replace

I need to replace a string depending on condition:
I need to replace the variable `term` by the variable `new_term` on the variable `string1` but only when we don't have `"IS_ADDITIF{{"` or `"IS_FUN_ADDITIF{{"` before.

Here is an example:

```
term = "DIGLYCERIDES"

new_term =  "IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}},"

string1 : " FOOD ADDITIVES DIGLYCERIDES  (DIGLYCERIDES  IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}}, IS_FUN_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}}, DIGLYCERIDES     )"

newstring1= string1.replace(term, new_term)
```

The result is the following :

```
newstring1 = " FOOD ADDITIVES IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}} (IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}} IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}}, IS_FUN_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}}, IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}} )"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression with two subsequent negative lookbehind assertion, then replace the match using `re.sub`

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('(?<!IS_ADDITIF\{\{)(?<!IS_FUN_ADDITIF\{\{)'+term, new_term, string1)

' FOOD ADDITIVES IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}},  (IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}},  IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}}, IS_FUN_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}}, IS_ADDITIF{{DIGLYCERIDES}},     )'
```

Understanding the pattern: `'(?<!IS_ADDITIF\{\{)(?<!IS_FUN_ADDITIF\{\{)'+term`

```py
(?<!IS_ADDITIF\{\{)       : String doesn't start with IS_ADDITIF{{
(?<!IS_FUN_ADDITIF\{\{)   : String doesn't start with IS_FUN_ADDITIF{{
term                      : Matching the value in term i.e. DIGLYCERIDES
```